# How to get the count of objects in ManyToMany field in template

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

Simply put, how can I get the number of objects that are in a ManyToMany field and then put the result in a template tag?

I couldn't find a built in template tag for this, is there one?

## Example:

```
followers = models.ManyToManyField(User)
followers = ('susan','john','doe')

{{ followers | count }} = '3'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming that your model is passed to the template as `my_model`, the correct syntax would be:

```
{{ my_model.followers.all.count }}
```

This behavior is explained in [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/db/queries/#many-to-many-relationships).